# Any short way for handling multiple queries in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I need to get multiple results from different queries on one table.
For example I need to get **Count, Sum, Average** of one table. Should I do like this or is there a shorter way?

```
  public function index()
    {
        $count = Patient::all()->count();
        $dateCount = Patient::where('date', date("Y-m-d"))->count();
        $loanAmount = DB::table('patients')->sum('loan_amount');
        $payAmount = DB::table('patients')->sum('pay_amount');
        return view('index', compact('count','dateCount','loanAmount' ,'payAmount'));
    }
```

If you see All queries are for one table to get specific results, So basically is there a short way to get these results not by single queries for each?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
public function index()
    {
        $patient = Patient::all();
        $count = $patient->count();
        $dateCount = Patient::today()->count();
        $loanAmount =  $patient->sum('loan_amount');
        $payAmount =  $patient->sum('pay_amount');
        return view('index', compact('count','dateCount','loanAmount' ,'payAmount'));
    }
```

Also you can create scope in your patient model:

```
public function scopeToday($query) {
  return $query->where('date', date("Y-m-d"));
}
```

Comment: Poldo Thanks, But still tow quires for single table!

Comment: @sajadHaibat you just lessen the query calls using $patient since it is returning collection you can use its method

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by DB query as below :

```
  $data=\DB::table('patients')
  ->selectRaw('count(id) as count,sum(loan_amount) as loanAmount,sum(pay_amount) as payAmount,sum(case when date = "'.date("Y-m-d").'" then 1 else 0 end) AS dateCount')
  ->first();
```

You can also do this using eloquent but it will return you collection.

```
  $data=Patient::selectRaw('count(id) as count,sum(loan_amount) as loanAmount,sum(pay_amount) as payAmount,sum(case when date = "'.date("Y-m-d").'" then 1 else 0 end) AS dateCount')
  ->first();
```